# \addplot graphics: maintaining image's aspect ratio despite different scaling of axes

Tags: pgfplots, graphics

I have created a plot using a sophisticated program and would like to put the content of that plot into `pgfplots' axis environment`. Naturally, `\addplot graphics` is the way to achieve this. The Image's aspect ratio (in this case) is `height > width`. However, the two axes have a different scaling with `x/cm >> y/cm`. Now, without `axis equal image`,`pgfplots` tends to create square plots. Switching on `axis equal image`, the plot will be created using `x/cm = y/cm`. Both options will result in a plot that does not respect the original image's aspect ratio. The only way I have found so far to preserve the aspect ratio, is to manually define the `x` and `y` `unit vectors`. But this might be rather hard to do, depending on the original image's size and the different scaling for the axes.
Is there an easy (and preferably automatic) way to create an image plot preserving the image's aspect ratio regardless of the axes' scalings?
The problem is illustrated by the code below.

```
\documentclass[10pt,varwidth=300pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{mwe}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-image-10x16}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
  xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=1,
  enlargelimits=false,
  axis equal image,
  x=1cm,y=16cm,%In this case, x and y are easy to calculate, but this will not always be the case
  ]
  \addplot graphics [xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=1] {example-image-10x16};
  \end{axis}
  \node[red,anchor=south] at (current axis.north) {This is what I want};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
  xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=1,
  enlargelimits=false,
  axis equal image,
  ]
  \addplot graphics [xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=1] {example-image-10x16};
 \end{axis}
 \node[red,anchor=south,align=center] at (current axis.north) {This is what I get without \\ manually defining unit vectors};
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
  xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=1,
  enlargelimits=false,
%   axis equal image,
  ]
  \addplot graphics [xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=1] {example-image-10x16};
 \end{axis}
 \node[red,anchor=south,align=center] at (current axis.north) {This is what I get without \\ manually defining unit vectors and \\ without axis equal image};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a feature request for `pgfplots`. The current implementation of `\addplot graphics` can squeeze a graphics into the axis. But reconfiguring the axis according to the natural size of the graphics is only implemented for the advanced `\addplot3 graphics[points=...]`.

Interestingly, the use-case illustrated in your example is actually simpler than the other ones... must have been forgotten.

Here is a draft for a macro which supports it:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\addplotgraphicsnatural[2][]{%
    \begingroup
    % set options in this local group (will be lost afterwards):
    \pgfqkeys{/pgfplots/plot graphics}{#1}%
    % measure the natural size of the graphics:
    \setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics{#2}}%
    %
    % compute the required unit vector ratio:
    \pgfmathparse{\wd0/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/plot graphics/xmax} - \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/plot graphics/xmin})}%
    \let\xunit=\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{\ht0/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/plot graphics/ymax} - \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/plot graphics/ymin})}%
    \let\yunit=\pgfmathresult
    %
    % configure pgfplots to use it.
    % The \xdef expands all macros except those prefixed by '\noexpand'
    % and assigns the result to a global macro named '\marshal'.
    \xdef\marshal{%
        \noexpand\pgfplotsset{unit vector ratio={\xunit\space \yunit}}%
    }%
    \endgroup
    %
    % use our macro here:
    \marshal
    %
    \addplot graphics[#1] {#2};
}   
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}
 \begin{axis}[
  axis on top,
  xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=1,
  enlargelimits=false,
  ]
  \addplotgraphicsnatural[xmin=0,xmax=10,ymin=0,ymax=1]{example-image-10x16}

  \end{axis}
  \node[red,anchor=south] at (current axis.north) {This is what I want};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The new macro reads the (mandatory) limits from the options and computes correct unit vector ratios accordingly.

My image `example-image-10x16` is

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}
\usepgfplotslibrary{patchplots}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[view={0}{90},axis equal image,hide axis]
    \addplot3[surf,shader=interp,patch type=bilinear,
        mesh/color input=explicit]
    coordinates {
        (0,0,0) [color=blue] (10,0,0) [color=green]

        (0,16,0) [color=yellow] (10,16,1) [color=red]
    };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That works perfectly, thanks! I was actually rather surprised, that no one had asked this before. Should I submit this as an official feature request somewhere? Or is this inofficial channel sufficient?

Comment: This is sufficient.

Comment: @ChristianFeuersänger has this macro made it into `1.11`? I just searched my (1.11) installation of pgfplots and the manual, but didn't find it. Of course I can use the macro from above. Thanks!

Comment: @Sebastian no, the feature request is still open.

Comment: If user use viewport to clip the picture, how can it still keep aspect ratio? e.g. origin image is (100,100), after viewport, it's (50,100), current logic still keep 1:1 but not 1:2.

Comment: @Beatlej your question has almost no visibility here, and the question is quite old. May I ask you to post a new question in which you show what you have so far and explain where and how you use viewport (perhaps based on this answer)? This will allow me and others to answer while keeping this site tidy.