# Problem combining tikzexternalize, tikzscale and external graphics

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-external, tikzscale

I have a problem when trying to scale and externalize a `tikzpicture` that includes an external graphics file.
Using the following code will result in an output of the document but the figure is not externalized into a separate file. Also, an error message is produced. When commenting `tikzexternalize` or using `input{test.tikz}` (i.e. not scaling the `tikzpicture`) everything works, though obviously without the corresponding effect. Also, `tikzpicture`s without an external graphic work just fine. Is there any way to combine `tikzscale` and `tikzexternalize` for `tikzpicture`s including an external graphic?

```
\documentclass[crop,10pt,border=0]{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{document}
\setlength{\textwidth}{510pt}
\begin{filecontents}{test.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) {\includegraphics[width=.25\textwidth]{example-image-a}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}
This is my document.
% \input{test.tikz}
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{test.tikz}
\end{document}
```

The error message is the following:

> ! Package tikz Error: Sorry, the system call 'pdflatex -enable-write18
>   -halt-on
>   -error -interaction=batchmode -jobname "external-test-figure0" "\def\tikzextern alrealjob{external-test}\input{external-test}"' did
>   NOT result in a usable outp ut file 'external-test-figure0' (expected
>   one of .pdf:.jpg:.jpeg:.png:). Please  verify that you have enabled
>   system calls. For pdflatex, this is 'pdflatex -sh ell-escape'.
>   Sometimes it is also named 'write 18' or something like that. Or m
>   aybe the command simply failed? Error messages can be found in
>   'external-test-f igure0.log'. If you continue now, I'll try to typeset
>   the picture.

Comment: Could you please post the complete error message? Is it one of those "`Sorry, ...`" ones?

Comment: @sdaau Yep, it's one of those, i'll add it to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I've found a workaround for this. As this has been bothering me for a long time and also includes some other issues to consider, I'll answer this step by step.

Task: Create a tikzpicture consisting of an external graphics (.png,.jpg,.pdf) that will not result in an error when used with `tikzscale` **and** `\tikzexternalize`.

Questions: Why a `tikzpicture` and not just `\includegraphics`?
 -Because I want to add some elements to the picture, which is easy to do in `tikz`.
Why using `tikzscale`?
 -Because I like to have my figures to have the same width as the text while keeping the `fontsize` of axes, nodes etc. independent of the figure's width. `tikzscale` is the tool for this.
Why `\tikzexternalize`?
 -Not using `\tikzexternalize` means that every `tikzpicture` is recompiled every time, the document is compiled. Depending on the `tikzpicture`'s complexity, this will take a lot of time.

The first approach:
The first approach can be seen in the original question. I placed a `node` in a `tikzpicture` and filled it with `\includegraphics`. This results in an error. The document is produced correctly, but the `tikzpicture`is not externalized i.e. saved in a separate .pdf.

The second approach:
In some earlier work I learned that `pgfplots`' `\addplot graphics` actually works with `tikzscale` and `\tikzexternalize`. The idea is now to put the exterael graphic in the `axis` environment and to hide the axes, ticks and labels. Let's assume we want a `tikzpicture` containing the following graphics (example-image-16x10.jpg included in the `mwe` package):
[image: example-image-16x10]
The code then reads as follows (the tikzpicture is written in a separate file `test.tikz` to load it with `tikzscale`'s `\includegraphics`). note the `ticks=none` and `axis lines=none` options to hide the axes, ticks and labels:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{test.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,
    ticks=none,
    axis lines=none,
    ]
    \addplot graphics [xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1] {example-image-16x10};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}
First we will include the picture as a normal graphics:
\begin{figure}[hb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-16x10}
    \caption{This is the figure without using \textit{tikzpicture}.}
\end{figure}
\newline Next, we include the figure as a \textit{tikzpicture} using \textit{tikzscale}.
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{test.tikz}
    \caption{This is my figure in \textit{tikzpicture}'s \textit{axis} environment. Unfortunaltely it is stretched into a square shape.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

When one compiles this code (twice), one will note, that the graphics in the `tikzpicture` is streched vertically, as `pgfplots`' `axis` environment tends to crate square shaped plots. To keep the original image's aspect ratio, one has to define a new `\addplot` command that will measure the original image's aspect ratio and scale the axes accordingly as demonstrated in an earlier question [\addplot graphics: maintaining image's aspect ratio despite different scaling of axes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175618/addplot-graphics-maintaining-images-aspect-ratio-despite-different-scaling-of).
The final code is then:

```
\documentclass[10pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{external}
\tikzexternalize[shell escape=-enable-write18]
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{mwe}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\addplotgraphicsnatural[2][]{%
    \begingroup
    \pgfqkeys{/pgfplots/plot graphics}{#1}%
    \setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics{#2}}%
    \pgfmathparse{\wd0/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/plot graphics/xmax} - \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/plot graphics/xmin})}%
    \let\xunit=\pgfmathresult
    \pgfmathparse{\ht0/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/plot graphics/ymax} - \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/plot graphics/ymin})}%
    \let\yunit=\pgfmathresult
    \xdef\marshal{%
        \noexpand\pgfplotsset{unit vector ratio={\xunit\space \yunit}}%
    }%
    \endgroup
    \marshal
    \addplot graphics[#1] {#2};
}   
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{filecontents}{test.tikz}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
    xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1,
    ticks=none,
    axis lines=none,
    ]
    \addplotgraphicsnatural [xmin=0,xmax=1,ymin=0,ymax=1] {example-image-16x10};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{filecontents}
First we will include the picture as a normal graphics:
\begin{figure}[hb]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{example-image-16x10}
    \caption{This is the figure without using \textit{tikzpicture}.}
\end{figure}
\newline Next, we include the figure as a \textit{tikzpicture} using \textit{tikzscale}.
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{test.tikz}
    \caption{This is my figure in \textit{tikzpicture}'s \textit{axis} environment. Unfortunaltely it is stretched into a square shape.}
    \end{figure}
\end{document}
```

This will produce the desired document as well as the externalized figure. I don't know whether there is a more elegant way to do this, but it works.