# pgfplots: retain aspect ratio of image

Tags: pgfplots, graphics, dimensions

I'm trying to insert an image with an axis, which can be achieved with the below code and the `pgfplots` package. How do I adjust this such that the axes have the same aspect ratio as the original image? Is there a setting that will read in the aspect ratio automatically and use this, or perhaps a way to automatically calculate the height from the image dimensions and defined axis width?

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={x axis},ylabel={y axis},
xtick distance=1,ytick distance=1,
width=14cm,
enlargelimits=false,
scale only axis=true,
]
\addplot graphics[xmin=0, xmax=5, ymin=0, ymax=5] {Images/test};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: Set `axis equal image`

Comment: That doesn't work. It changes the image to a square (original is a long thin rectangle).

Comment: Ah yes, sorry, I just noticed that you want differently scaled axes. Does [\addplot graphics: maintaining image's aspect ratio despite different scaling of axes](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175618/addplot-graphics-maintaining-images-aspect-ratio-despite-different-scaling-of) help?

Comment: I found that earlier and I've been reading through it, but I'm not quite sure how to translate it for my example, or whether it is even applicable. Still working on it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's a slightly adapted version of Christian Feuersänger's answer to [\addplot graphics: maintaining image's aspect ratio despite different scaling of axes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175618/addplot-graphics-maintaining-images-aspect-ratio-despite-different-scaling-of) (the only difference being that this version makes sure that the smaller of the unit vectors is 1):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\begin{document}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\addplotgraphicsnatural[2][]{%
    \begingroup
    % set options in this local group (will be lost afterwards):
    \pgfqkeys{/pgfplots/plot graphics}{#1}%
    % measure the natural size of the graphics:
    \setbox0=\hbox{\includegraphics{#2}}%
    %
    % compute the required unit vector ratio:
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xfactor}{\wd0/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/plot graphics/xmax} - \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/plot graphics/xmin})}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yfactor}{\ht0/(\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/plot graphics/ymax} - \pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/plot graphics/ymin})}\yfactor%
    % The smaller of the unit vectors should be 1, so the other needs to be scaled appropriately
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\xunit}{\xfactor<\yfactor ? 1 : \xfactor/\yfactor}
    \pgfmathsetmacro{\yunit}{\xfactor<\yfactor ? \yfactor/\xfactor : 1}
    %
    % configure pgfplots to use it.
    % The \xdef expands all macros except those prefixed by '\noexpand'
    % and assigns the result to a global macro named '\marshal'.
    \xdef\marshal{%
        \noexpand\pgfplotsset{unit vector ratio*={\xunit\space \yunit}}%
    }%
    \endgroup
    %
    % use our macro here:
    \marshal
    %
    \addplot graphics[#1] {#2};
}   
\makeatother

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false, axis equal image]
\addplotgraphicsnatural [xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=10] {snake.png};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[enlargelimits=false, axis equal image]
\addplotgraphicsnatural [xmin=0, xmax=10, ymin=0, ymax=10] {giraffe.png};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```